# Sending an EMF file to a specific printer / tray in WPF application

Tags: wpf, printing, .emf

I've got a WPF application that needs to send pre-generated EMF files to a specified printer/tray.

I don't want to show the PrintDialog; the actual printer/tray is configured before hand.  I also don't need to actually view the EMF file either; but rather just send it to the printer.

So far, all my R&D into this has led to is a bunch of posts that are 5 years old dealing with EMF and WPF and how it isn't supported.

Has anybody had any luck with this before?  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was easier than I thought.  You can do this via a `Image` control, and use of a converter.  This example takes the file location of the emf file, and puts it into a WPF usercontrol that I then send to a printer.

In XAML:

```
<Grid Margin="12">
    <Image Source="{Binding Path=FileName, Converter={StaticResource emfImageConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"></Image>
</Grid>
```

and your converter class:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(string), typeof(BitmapImage))]
public class EmfImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var fileName = (string)value;
        if (fileName == null || !File.Exists(fileName))
            return new BitmapImage();
        using (var stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open))
        {
            return GetImage(stream);
        }
    }

    internal BitmapImage GetImage(Stream fileStream)
    {
        var img = Image.FromStream(fileStream);
        var imgBrush = new BitmapImage { CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad, CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat };
        imgBrush.BeginInit();
        imgBrush.StreamSource = ConvertImageToMemoryStream(img);
        imgBrush.EndInit();
        return imgBrush;
    }

    public MemoryStream ConvertImageToMemoryStream(Image img)
    {
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        return ms;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```